# SQL Database to php website with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I seem to be stuck on a concept in database query and website development.

I have a website that will reflect what data is stored in a database and the website needs to change depending on that data: therefore, my menu system will not be hardcoded in.  It builds my menu system based off a query of all the models in my database.  The action of clicking on the menu will show tables without changing the page (a simple javascript "showtables" function). like so:

```
        function showTables(TABLE_NAME)
{
    if(TABLE_NAME != "PRINTER_TABLE")
    {
        document.getElementById("PRINTER_TABLE").style.display ="none";

    }
    if(TABLE_NAME != "show_ALL_PRINTERS")
    {
        document.getElementById("show_ALL_PRINTERS").style.display ="none";
    }
    document.getElementById(TABLE_NAME).style.display ="block";
}
```

I did not include all of my other if statements because there are about 15 of them.  These statements will hide everything and the only show the formatted table of "TABLE_NAME" at the end of that script.

My problem is that, if all of the data will not be hardcoded in either HTML or PHP, I need to pass into my function "showTables" a model type or ID that will come from my query.

My Menu system code snipet:

```
     <li class="hasmore"><a href="#" onClick="showTables('show_ALL_PRINTERS')"><span>Printer Parts</span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
      <?php
        include 'connection.php';

        $query = "SELECT * FROM all_printers";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            #echo "<h3>" . $row['printer_model'] . "</h3>";
            echo "<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"showTables('PRINTER_TABLE'")\">" .$row['printer_model']."</a></li>\n";
        }
    ?>
```

This puts the model into the menu system and the "PRINTER_TABLE" will access my showTables function, which then will show that table.  But there are many different printer models and I need to tell my table query what specific model to get info on.

I hope this makes sense as there is a lot of logic behind it.  Maybe there is an easier way..?

In my tables I have:

```
    <table id="table">
    <thead>
          <tr>
              <th scope="col" id="table">Type</th>
              <th scope="col" id="table">Size</th>
              <th scope="col" id="table">S/N</th>
              <th scope="col" id="table">Model</th>
              <th scope="col" id="table">Connection Type</th>
              <th scope="col" id="table">Surplus</th>
              <th scope="col" id="table">Amount</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>     
            <?php
            include 'connection.php';
            $query_misc = "SELECT * FROM all_parts WHERE part_type='MISC'";
            $result_misc = mysql_query($query_misc);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_misc))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><div align=\"center\">".$row['part_type']."</div></td>";
                echo "<td><div align=\"center\">".$row['part_size']."</div></td>";
                echo "<td><div align=\"center\">".$row['part_sn']."</div></td>";
                echo "<td><div align=\"center\">".$row['part_model']."</div></td>";
                echo "<td><div align=\"center\">".$row['part_connection']."</div></td>";
                echo "<td><div align=\"center\">".$row['part_surplus']."</div></td>";
                echo "<td><div align=\"center\">".$row['part_temp_amount']."/".$row['part_amount']."</div></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
```

..... etc

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I do now know how to put what I click on, into the url properly..

```
    <?
        $query = 'SELECT printer_id, printer_model FROM printer_table WHERE 1 ORDER BY name';
        $products = mysql_query($query);
        while ($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($products)) :
    {
        echo "<li><a href=\"inventory_admin.php?product_id='".$product['printer_id']."'\" onclick=\"toggleVisibility('".$product['printer_model']."')\">" .$product['printer_model']."</a></li>\n";
    }

     ?>
```

or

```
    <li><a href="inventory_admin.php?product_id=<?=$product['printer_id']?>" onclick="toggleVisibility('<?=$product['printer_model']?>')"><?=$product['printer_model']?></a></li>
```

doesnt work properly, because i need to call the suggested part list php part, but do not know where to do so..

EDIT:

I placed that php within a div and the echos will fill out my table, but how am I suppose to call that div to only run when that onclick action?  I know that is not how divs work, It would seem I would need a JS function but I know you cannot do php within JS.  AJAX perhaps?

**EDIT----------------------------------------------------**

The call here to the DB is correct, tested it manually without any errors, but I am still receiving a syntax error upon loading my home page.  Here is my call to the DB via PHP...

```
    <?
    if (!isset($_GET['action']))
    {
        //If not isset -> set with dumy value
        $_GET['action'] = "undefine";
    } 
    include 'connection.php';
    $query = 'SELECT ppart_table.* FROM ppart_table LEFT JOIN printer_part_relation ON ppart_table.part_id = printer_part_relation.part_id WHERE printer_part_relation.printer_id ='.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['printer_id']);

    $parts = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed with error: ".mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($parts)) 
    {
        echo table blah blah    
    }       
?>
```

I have tried supressing all errors via this:

```
    <?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>
```

And the syntax error at page load still exist.

My home page of this site does NOT have the "product_id=" after mysite.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using PHP's PDO class for database access. I would also recommend using JQuery for all of you javascripting. It makes things VERY simple. It would also be advantagious to keep your display code away from your business logic (two languages should for the most part not be in the same source file ie: HTML/PHP/Javascript). I will stick with what is familiar for now however. perhaps something like this?

**menu**

```
<ul>

   <?
      $query = 'SELECT id, name FROM product_category_table WHERE 1 ORDER BY name';
      $product_categories = mysql_query($query);
      while ($product_category = mysql_fetch_assoc($product_categories)) :
   ?>

   <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('<?= $product_category['id'] ?>')">$product_category['name']</a>
      <ul id="<?= $product_category['id'] ?>" style="display: none;">

         <?
            $query = 'SELECT id, name FROM product_table WHERE category_id = ' . $product_category['id'] . ' ORDER BY name';
            $products = mysql_query($query);
            while ($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($products)) :
         ?>

         <li><a href="thispage.php?product_id=<?= $product['id'] ?>"><?= $product['name'] ?></a></li>

         <?
            endwhile;
         ?>

      </ul>
   </li>

   <?
      endwhile;
   ?>

</ul>
```

**javascript**

```
function toggleVisibility(category) {
   var element = document.getElementById(category);
   if (element.style.display == 'none') {
      element.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
      element.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

**part list**

```
<?
$query = 'SELECT part_table.* FROM part_table LEFT JOIN product_to_part_associations_table ON parts_table.id = product_to_part_associations_table.part_id WHERE product_to_part_associations_table.product_id = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['product_id']);
$parts = mysql_query($query);
while ($part = mysql_fetch_assoc($parts)) {
   echo part table blah blah
}
?>
```

**db tables**

```
product_category_table
id, name, etc

product_table
id, category_id, name, etc

part_table
id, name, etc

part_to_product_association_table
id, product_id, part_id
```

set the proper indexes on your table columns for speed. the part_to_product_association table allows for a many to many relationship between records in the product table and records in the parts table (needed in the case one part could be used in multiple products, and one product can use multiple parts).

Comment: this is using javascript to show/hide a submenu. you could also use a current category in a link's GET variable, and use it to show/hide the right submenus during the page's load.

Comment: Thank you for the input towards my task.  I have many years of programming in many different languages behind me, but this is the first time I've ever tackled JS/PHP.  So you are recommending I have a separate file for my php calls and JS functions?  

I am understanding your menu idea, JS idea, but the part list does not need a join of any sort and I do already have my DB mapped out/created.  I am making SELECT statements from the DB and communication is working properly into the tables I have created with a CSS file.

Comment: I have been trying to grasp the $_REQUEST / $_GET / $_POST functions to have communication between what I click on and have that item being displayed into the table, but cannot seem to get it to work in one file.  Is this where I should have multiple files to manage communication between the DB and the webpage?

Comment: @Foxtrot it's easy, if you have a form with method post, all the form's field values will be placed in the $_POST super global array in the PHP script that the form is submitted to. if the forms method is get, then they will be placed in the $_GET super global array. you can also put variables in the $_GET superglobal array through the url that you use to request the script, so the link index.php?foo=bar&this=that, will cause $_GET['foo'] to = 'bar' and $_GET['this'] to = 'that' in the index.php script if someone were to follow the link.

Comment: $_REQUEST holds everything that is in post, get, cookies and more combined into one array.

Comment: Can you edit your above code to reflect my database? I am trying to follow what you are calling, but am having difficulty doing so:

Comment: I'm sorry : disregard my last messages.  I think I am going to have to change my db, but i dont require a category table.  My question for that is for the part_to_product_association_table, I think in that table it would have to hold the total value of objects literally instock.  Would it just be another column in that table? And I would presume product_id and part_id are foreign keys to the product_table and part_table?

Comment: Also, where would I call the part list .php you provided above?

Comment: mypage.php?product_id=<?=$product['printer_id']?>  is now what is in the URL with this method provided.

Comment: @Foxtrot part_to_product_association_table would ONLY link a product record to a part record, letting the system know that that part can be used with that product. nothing else. instock values would be held in the part record itself instead.

Comment: @Foxtrot the part list would be placed where you list the parts for that particular product

Comment: @Foxtrot, it's true you may not need a category table unless you wanted to store more info about each category, like a category description. would also save on the back end if someone were creating a new part in the db, and you had to generate a list of categories that the new product could belong to. currently you would have to select distinct categories from the product table (thus ant trailing through the product table). with it's own table, you just simply pull the list.

Comment: plus think about what happens when someone creates a new catagory in the system. are you just going to let them enter whateever text they want into the category field for new products? this would lead to inconsitent spellings of existing categories and oy... the troubles

Comment: I understand that concern... as I do have that.  But I only have three categories(tables): Computers, Computer parts, and Printers -> now converted to three tables: parts, printers, and association.  I do not see it *ever* expanding beyond that.... If they have a new product, it will be inserted into the respective table: New Hard drive would be placed within computer parts. etc.

Comment: @Foxtrot you should get a PHP/MySQL book. It seems you are making things more complicated than needed. as for your edit, after they click the link, your PHP would build the correct list of parts based on the $_GET variable during the page load. I do not understand where you are having issues.

Comment: I apologize that I don't seem to be following your recommendation and maybe I am explaining my question wrong...  I was just wondering where that PHP code should be located with my code: Not within any div(s) but still in my <body>   /*  php code  */  </body>

Comment: @Foxtrot PHP code is unrelated to HTML tags in any way. PHP code gets run server side before any of the HTML is rendered on the client side. PHP code must be in between <?php and ?> markers however, so that PHP know what to process and what to leave alone. All your PHP processing could be at the top of the page, then only small bits of PHP would be used in your HTML almost like template markers showing where to print the already created PHP variables. You could also just place the PHP processing right where you want to print out the list of items. You could set it up however you want really.

Comment: @Foxtrot the only thing that matters to PHP in the way of where it is located is echo and print statement, as they will print to the page wherever they are placed. similarly the shortcut <?= $variable ?> also prints out the variable wherever it is placed within the page.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations.  It all seems to make sense, and yes I have been trying to do this the a$$ backwards way.  I figure I am going to change a good portion of my code, but the only difficult part is properly using echo with the proper quotes and apostrophes to still be able to make my php calls, etc. because it has to all be in "_" but that Im sure I can find elsewhere on the net.  Thank you again.

Comment: @Foxtrot I typically enclose all of my strings within single quotes ', and use double quotes " in my html. or you just put the entire string into a variable and echo that. if it's a large block of html, you would typically just close PHP ?> and put whatever you want. there are also ways to escape quotes in strings of course.

Comment: So almost everything is working, I just have to build the DB and format my tables, but with that php, I have to suppress $_GET[action]= "undefine";  I am able to get a reply from my DB with that in there, but I still have a syntax error at the home page... I think its because I don't have anything set in my url after my home address.  The code you suggested adds in the .php?printer_id=1 when i click on the first menu.  But I am receiving a syntax error at load.  See Edit above for that specific call, because I am almost positive the call is correct (tested it directly to the db).See edit above

Comment: @Foxtrot is it a PHP syntax error? if so, which line? is it a mysql error? if so, what is the error? also, the line "echo table blah blah" will definitely give you a syntax error. I didn't fill that line in because I was in a hurry.

Comment: lol no I'm not that dumb when it comes to coding :P I know, I took out my echo because it was long and not erroring there.  The site says: Query failed with error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1...... which makes me believe that the syntax in that first query is incorrect.  I tested the code without that php? in the page and there is no error, so that points to that query.

Comment: The error implies that the variable $_GET['printer_id'] is empty. Can you test this? The link to this page should have "?printer_id=" then the actual id of the printer at the end, or something to that effect in order to populate the $_GET['printer_id'] variable.

Comment: That is what I figured, but can I just set the start page to be at mywebpage.php?printer_id='NULL'  ? Or some form of that?

Comment: @Foxtrot if you did that, what printer would you show them when they click that? is that link for the printer category in general instead of a specific printer? i'm not sure what that link is. if it's not for a printer, perhaps the link should be to a separate script entirely. not sure what the whole scenario is, so use best judgement.

Comment: Also, I plan on having other items on this site, with the same type of interaction, click on a link and run the query through this $_GET method, but it wont have the 'printer_id' in the url, so wouldn't the other query fail on load as well( the query on general parts, so something like 'all_parts_id=')?

Comment: By default, I do not want anything to be shown with the printers at that page. The user interaction with clicking the printer menu, and pulling the tables of which printer they clicked on is working.  But I do not want that script to be ran on initial page load, I think.  Can i just have that php in an entirely different file, and use the <? include  printer_script.php; ?>    ?

Comment: @Foxtrot if each product you plan on displaying is formatted differently and has different info, you should put them into different pages (scripts). then link to whichever page is appropriate. your initial landing page should not be the same page as your view printer X page. this way you don't have to worry about whether $_GET['print_id'] is set on your printer displaying page. you can assume that it will be because the only links leading there have it set.

Comment: typically when starting off, people make a header and footer script, and include those in each page. when you get better, you will start using classes instead, and when you get even better, you will start using an MVC type modal to display pages.

Comment: My landing page is now different from the printer php script page and I have been try to link them to that script but I have to place the returned results from that php call in a div or equivalent location so I can format it properly.  I cannot simply use an <? php include 'myphpscript.php'; ?> within that div, because I will get the same syntax error.  I have looked into AJAX implementation so it would become an onclick action and not run the php script until that happens [ therefore avoiding that error ] but that seems like it is unnecessary.  Is there another way to do this ?

Comment: @Foxtrot you have two pages and you are trying to link them to "that" script. I am confused. why would you ever get an error if you only put the script in the "display a printer" page?

Comment: I have mypage.php and then the action of clicking on the desired printer changes the url to mypage.php?product_id='1'  (1 just being an example).  When this happens, the php script needs to be ran, as appose to having the script running at the mypage.php load [ seeing as at page load it does not have the printer_id='' in the URL. At the same time, the data returned from the php script will be formatted within a DIV in the main body.  Therefore, I do not know where to put the <?php //myscript ?>    Does that make sense?

Comment: [The script is separate from my main but I need to call the script file within the main somewhere.]  Doing an include 'myscript.php' will give me that same error obviously

Comment: @Foxtrot we are back to where we started... i'm not sure you understood my last few comments. mypage.php should not be linked to without the printer_id variable. if you need a separate landing page that does not display printers, it should be a separate page all together. this way you will not have the problem you are describing.

Comment: Ugh, fail upon me.  You are correct.  Sorry.  Just my issue is that I dont want to have separate pages per everything that the user clicks on, when the menu's need to be dynamic and display the tables reflecting what the user clicked on in the middle of the page[which needs to be handled in a DIV, with that change visibility feature]

Comment: @Foxtrot you would only have different pages set up for different data you want to display, like all printer displaying links would point to one single page, just with different printer_ids in the URL. you can keep things like page head, menu, page footer in separate scripts that you can call using include(). this way it is less cumbersome to create multiple pages for each section of your website, and you then only have to change the one source file to modify these page sections for the entire website.

Comment: ideally you would use an MVC type settup however which uses a front controller to direct all incomming requests to different controller classes, which would then use models to set up a view for output.